# Persisting mongoose model with array of objectId references

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoDB for the persistence needs of my restful API.

I have an Events schema with an exported model. I also have a Location schema with an exported model.

The Event has an array of Locations in its schema representing a oneToMany relationship.

I make a HTTP POST request to my API to persist an Event with a list of associated Locations as follows:

```
{
"name": "My first advertised event",
"shortDescription": "Some kind of event",
"fullDescription": "This is a massive detailed description of an event, honestly.",
"location": [
    "5a49121b4f1e572d48785ddd", 
    "2e21b4f1e572d48785dcb"
    ]
```

}

I get the following error, which I can;t seem to find a solution to:

```
        "_message": "Event validation failed",
    "message": "Event validation failed: location: Cast to Array failed for value \"[ '5a49121b4f1e572d48785ddd', '2e21b4f1e572d48785dcb' ]\" at path \"location\"",
    "name": "ValidationError"
```

My relevant schemas and service are found below:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Location = require('./location');

const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    shortDescription: String,
    fullDescription: String,
    location : [
        { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Location' }
        ]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event');
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GeoLocation = require('../common/mongoose/model/geoLocation').geoLocation();

const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    location : GeoLocation
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location');
```

```
const Hal = require('hal');
const Event = require('./event.js');

module.exports = {

createNewEvent: (req, res) => {
    let locations = [];
    req.body.location.map(loc => locations.push(loc));
   var event = new Event({
        name : req.body.name,
        shortDescription : req.body.shortDescription,
        fullDescription : req.body.fullDescription,
        location : req.body.location
    });
   event.save()
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send({message: err}))
        .then(data => res.send(data)
        );
    },
}
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue for hours but can't seem to work it out. If I save with a single reference in the json then it works, even thought the Event schema expects an oneToMany relationship.

Im fairly new to mongoDB so I accept that I probably am missing a fundamental concept. If anybody can help me to learn what I'm doing wrong i would be really grateful.

Also, happy new year! :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to amend my service call to :

```
    createNewEvent: (req, res) => {
   var event = new Event({
        name : req.body.name,
        shortDescription : req.body.shortDescription,
        fullDescription : req.body.fullDescription,
    });
    req.body.location.map(x => event.location.push(x));
    event.save()
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send({message: err}))
        .then(data => res.send(data)
        );
}
```